# c++ it seems that variable doesn't " flush " with multi thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

is_master_ def:

```
volatile bool is_master_;
```

**is_master_** value is set to true by another thread , but It seems that **is_master_** value dosnt flush (it doesn't cout the FATAL ERROR HAS OCCURRED... ). If i add cout << "foo" <

```
void MasterSlaveSynchronize::validateSingleMaster(){
    if(is_master_){
        cout << "FATAL ERROR HAS OCCURRED BOTH MASTER";
        if(!is_leader_master_){
            cout << "CHOSE AS VICTIM IN MASTER-MATSER. SET THIS HOST AS SLAVE";
            is_master_ = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The caller code:

```
while(1){
        int n = recvfrom(sockId, buf, HEARBEAT_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from,
                &length);
        if (n < 0) {
            REGISTER_ERROR("Failed to recieved hearbeat");
        } else {
            gettimeofday(&instance_->last_hearbeat_got_, NULL);
            instance_->validateSingleMaster();
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it does, but because you don't use a newline your output stream doesn't flush.

Comment: What's the relationship between `is_master_` and `is_leader_master_`?

Comment: @MarceloCantos there are 2 different booleans.

Comment: @paddy you are right!!!!! Thanks, can you write it as an answer in order to mark it? can you please explain? Thank you!!!

Comment: I would advise you to read a bit more on `volatile` values and threads, while you are working on this. You would probably be better off using *atomics* than just volatiles here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Tahnk you for your comment ? Do i need to use atmoics even for boolean (1 byte ) ? Why did you say better of , is there any conflict between them ? Shouldnt i use both in order to be on the safe side? Thank you

Comment: @user1495181: well, I am not *that* knowledgeable about threads and memory models, however I do know that depending on use `volatile` in C++ (unlike Java) is not sufficient to guarantee much. The problem is not necessarily the size, when coming to atomicity, it's the optimizations a compiler and/or CPU can do in reordering the memory reads and writes operations (or eliding them). `std::atomic<bool>` are built specifically to match the CPU primitives, so that you will get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted me to post my comment as an answer:

> Maybe it does, but because you don't use a newline your output stream
>   doesn't flush.

This behaviour is explained reasonably well here:

[Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)